# Python flask Stripe payment integration with live keys throwing an error

Tags: python, reactjs, flask

I am integrating stripe payment for my python flask backend works fine with test mode keys with the following code. But throwing error with live mode keys? Does anyone know what is the issue?

Code:

```
intent = stripe.PaymentIntent.create(
            amount=data['amount'],
            currency=data['currency'],
            receipt_email=data['email'],
            payment_method_types=["card"]
                   
        )
        cust_id = 'pi_'+str(intent['client_secret']).split('_')[1]
        
        result = stripe.PaymentIntent.confirm(cust_id,payment_method="pm_card_visa")
```

```
Error: "Request req_M2efbyAuAuCPRG: You cannot use the test ID 'pm_card_visa' in live mode. If you are testing your integration, please use your test mode API keys instead."
Type: "InvalidRequestError"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use `pm_card_visa` on live mode, where `pm_card_visa` is a shortcut to the 4242424242424242 **test card**.
Instead you need to use proper Payment Method ID - https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment

Comment: Just to add: if you want to use `payment_method`, you need to get the payment method from Stripe API. However, if you want to initialize a payment without taking that step, just omit it from the PaymentIntent request